# Passing in modules as types

Tags: system-verilog

I have a bunch of 'unique' modules that share some common fields. I'd like to create a module that can reference this, say, by upward name referencing. Is it possible to pass in a module type as a parameter that can be used inside? I tried this:

```
  3 module A;
  4   int flag = 0;
  5 endmodule
  6
  7 module B;
  8   int flag = 1;
  9 endmodule
 10
 11 module C;
 12   int flag = 2;
 13 endmodule
 14
 15 module Bind #(parameter type T=A);
 16   initial begin
 17     $display("flat = %0d",t.flag);
 18   end
 19 endmodule
 20
 21 module tb;
 22   bind A Bind#(A) u_bound;
 23 endmodule
```

But I got the following compile errors:

```
-- Compiling module B
-- Compiling module C
-- Compiling module Bind
** Error: test.sv(15): (qverilog-2730) Undefined variable: 'A'.
** Error (suppressible): test.sv(15): (qverilog-2987) Illegal expression as initializer for type parameter 'T'.
-- Compiling module tb
** Error: (qverilog-13069) test.sv(22): near ";": syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting '('.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only datatypes can be parameterized as types.

You could use this little known feature of Verilog that all function call names search upwards

```
 module A;
    int flag = 0;
    function int get_flag(); return flag; endfunction
 endmodule

  module B;
    int flag = 1;
    function int get_flag(); return flag; endfunction
  endmodule

  module C;
    int flag = 2;
    function int get_flag(); return flag; endfunction
  endmodule

  module Bind #(parameter type T=A);
    initial begin
      $display("flag = %0d",get_flag);
    end
  endmodule

  module tb;
    A aa();
    bind A Bind# u_bound();
  endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks @dave_59! Alas, the modules are RTL and at this moment I don't have the flexibility of adding a function into them. That's a pretty nifty trick though. Can you give an LRM reference for anyone else that will come across this?

Comment: Section *23.8.1 Task and function name resolution* explains this. It was in the original Verilog spec. You should be able to put these functions in RTL. They are synthesizable, but will be ignored since no RTL will reference them.

Comment: Another option is to put the names of the signals you want to reference in the port list of the `Bind` module.